# Ignore Persistent Cookies in Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, asp.net-identity

I am looking for a way to set up a session in ASP.NET that will ignore any persistent cookies on a user's computer, and force any cookies created within that session to be session cookies.

Effectively, I wish to be able to replicate the behaviour shown in 'In Private Browsing', where the session is considered an isolated browsing session. The reason for this is to allow my application to be able to leverage OAuth authentication from social providers; however have the app force the provider to request the user's credentials when logging in, regardless if they are currently logged in to that provider.

I acknowledge that OAuth is intended to have this behaviour, of automatically identifying that a user is logged into the provider. However, it is considered necessary for this application that "remember me" functionality is ignored.

I would also prefer to not have to remind users that they should either not use "remember me" on their accounts, or insist that they use private browsing.

The app is built in using Asp.Net MVC 4 and is using Identity. I had hoped that their might be something within `CookieAuthenticationOptions`; however, I have been unsuccessful in finding something that might offer me this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Connect has a special parameter "prompt" to control this: Try adding "prompt=login".

See chapter 3.1.2.1:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: This looks very promising, thank-you. 
However, how/where do I add this parameter? I had thought that I could just add this to the AuthenticationProperties Dictionary within ExecuteResult; however this had no effect.

Comment: Additionally, I am trying to use Googe, Facebook, Windows.Live, Twitter, and LinkedIn. Will this method cover all of these, or will I be required to implement a different solution for each? For example, looking through the Microsoft.Owin.Security handlers on [KataProject](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) suggests that only Google uses OpenID.